# Must a C++ Standard Library be implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, std

1. Must a conforming C++ Standard Library Implementation be implemented in C++?
2. If not, is it allowed to do magic things that are not doable in pure C++ & Standard Library & some implementation defined behaviour?

---

- *I am aware that there are parallel implementations that rely on extensions (in pre C++11 at least), but are they really conforming?*
- *I couldn't find any requirement in the standard, but maybe my standard-fu is weak today*

Comment: I'm reminded of a quote about the State of the Union: "If the President buys Congress a subscription to the Wall Street Journal, he's fulfilled his Constitutional obligations!"

Comment: The "as if" rule allows the implementation to choose any implementation it likes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Actually, it is even prescribed by the Standard that `#include <map>` (for example) could simply import a pre-stored AST and not refer to a file, at all.

Comment: Let me accept this. Dietmars answer is imho less concrete than yours.

Answer (score 19):

There is no requirement at all how the standard C++ library (or the standard C library for that matter) is implemented. All the library needs to achieve is to implement the documented and specified interface. How this is done is entirely up to the implementation. Part of standard libraries are often implemented by the compiler in some magic way and in C++2011 there are several interfaces which actually **cannot** be implemented using standard C++2011 language facilities! Primarily this is true for some of the traits in `<type_traits>` but there are other things.

Just for the reference: how C++ is implemented and what it actually really means to conform to the standard is held extremely vague. The relevant clause is 1.4 [intro.compliance]. It merely speaks about diagnostics being issued and what a program has to do, constraint to resource limitations, however.

Comment: +1: Being a moderate template writer myself, I am really curious which type-traits that would be.

Comment: You don't need any recent additions to find things which can't be implemented using standard language facilities.  The language itself has no concept of IO, so `filebuf` et al. need something more (Posix, anyway---but that's not standard C++).  In fact, the fact that something is useful, even to a small community, but cannot be implemented with standard language constructs, is often a motivation to add it to the library.  (In C, this was the argument given for `offsetof`.)

Comment: @phresnel: I don't have a readily available comprehensive list of things which can't be implemented without compiler support. However, things like `is_trivially_default_constructible` would need to test information about how the default constructor is actually declared or if it is synthesized. Several compiler implement various type traits but they often implement more than is absolutely necessary because the compiler can be a lot more efficient in telling certain traits instead of inspecting a somewhat contrived instantiation.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I have refined my second question slightly to include "implementation defined behaviour". Should that not saturate the IO requirement?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, yes, the standard doesn't define anything like how file descriptors are accessed. However, if you are on a platform where you can use the file descriptor family of function (e.g. POSIX platform) you can implement all the file stream operations in C++ without calls to the corresponding system calls. I would think this counts as "implemented in C++" but I agree that other definitions of what this means are quite reasonable, possibly even more so.

Comment: @phresnel I don't think so, at least not in terms of the C++ standard.  There is no language construct in C++ which will transfer bytes from the OS into your program.  And the C++ standard says that anything not specified otherwise by the standard is undefined behavior.  (And this is language lawyering at its most extreme---in practice, you always have other standards, like Posix, at your disposition, which do define the behavior.)

Comment: @DietmarKühl How?  How do you get the bytes from the OS into a C++ object (array of `char`, or whatever) without going outside the C++ language (which as far as I can tell, doesn't even acknowledge the existence of bytes outside the program)?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree that use e.g. of POSIX functions is outside the scope of the C++ standard and without using corresponding functionality (whether it is C library, traps, or whatever) you won't be able to implement e.g. the file streams. Obviously, I agree that the standard, including its library, can't be implemented in standard C++ without these.

Comment: *C++2011* is correct in a sense, but isn't it called *C++11*?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, only the interface needs to be C++.

Comment: What do you mean by this? `#include <some-std-header>` doesn't have to include a file: it may just notify the compiler about certain definitions to be made available in the translation unit, i.e. I don't think the interface needs to be in C++, either. It somewhat depends on what you consider an `interface`, though...

Comment: I guess so (but guesses should not be part of a question :)), too, but I was more looking for references or quotations.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I believe this technique was actually used by Visual Age.