# What is relationship between some C and Unix functions

Tags: c, linux, unix

For example, in C, we have `fopen`, and in Unix, we have `open`. There are some subtle differences between them, but they are doing the same thing.

There are also many other functions that both existing in C and Unix, what is the relationship between them? Which one should I prefer?

Comment: Basic difference, `C` is a language, `Unix` is OS.

Comment: If you are targetting Unix system, prefer standard library functions anyway. If the function is not available, prefer POSIX functions. If not available use your local SO function ... *and if not available write your own*.

Comment: [What's the difference between “C system calls” and “C library routines”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572942/whats-the-difference-between-c-system-calls-and-c-library-routines)

Comment: That was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open

Answer (score 3):

[fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is returning a `FILE*` on success, but [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is returning a file descriptor on success, so they are not doing the same (since not giving the same type).

However, on Linux, `fopen` is internally using the `open` [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (and some others too...).

`<stdio.h>` file handles are handling buffering. With system calls like `open` and `read` you'll better do your own buffering.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24993449/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563270/841108) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Be aware that on Linux, from the user-land application point of view, a system call is essentially an *atomic elementary* operation (e.g. the `SYSCALL` or `SYSENTER` machine instruction).

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out which system calls are executed (by a given process or command).

On Linux, the [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) is implementing standard functions (like `fprintf` ....) above system calls.

Many system calls don't have any libc counterpart (except their wrapper), e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 3):

**open** is a system call from Unix systems.
**fopen** is the standard c function to open a file.

There's some advantages of using fopen rather than open.

- It's mult-platform, as it's C standard, you can port your program to any platform with a C compiler.
- It supports use of C standard functions, (i.e: fprintf, fscanf)
- If you are handling with text files, those functions can deal with different new lines characters (Unix/Windows)